# How to constrain generic to a union?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, union-types

Does anybody know how to express: "constrain the generic so it must be a union with a certain type (in this case: null)"?

```ts
type Test<value_T extends Enforce_null_union>

Test<number | null> // Valid
Test<string | null> // Valid
Test<number> // Invalid, must be a union containing `null`
Test<number> // Invalid, must be a union containing `null`
```

Comment: Please include any attempts you tried so far.

Comment: Where do you need this type? Why not just write something along the lines of `type Test<T> = T | null`? But if you really care about the type parameter, a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) might help (though it won't guard against `Test<any>`).

Comment: You could extend it yourself inside your type, as @Bergi suggested.
If `Test` is a complex type and you need to reuse `T` a lot you can define another type and give it a constant default value `type Test<T, F extends T | null = T | null>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a similar idea than Nadia's answer, this should also work ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKhDOwA8MoQB7AgOwCbygApsBXAGzLUx31igH4oTsBrbAewHdsoAuKbBABuEAE4BKAHxQAvFADeAXwBQy0JFgBGOXERJSAWwBGYqAB8B5MtID0NqADUAhmQCWuNeGgwATDoTIiKKu2ADm5pbGphakFLb2zm4e6t4AzP56hiaiEZrxUACS2EIu7gA0UAYkiFAmUE5M2K7sPADGLcBOISHhAAaxZL2eGjAALBnIWWL5RSVJFVU1dQ3MzW0dXU1hUP1WQ8pAA)):

```
type Test<T extends (null extends T ? unknown : never)> = T
```

Answer (score 4):

This seems to work for your case: `type Test<T extends (U extends null ? T : unknown), U = T extends null ? T:never>={}`

Comment: I hadn't seen this pattern before, very clever. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKhDOwA8MoQB7AgOwCbygAoBVNTHfKbAVwBtaoB+WKALimuwGtsB7Ad2wBKADRRSAXhYYseAjXpMW7bBABuEAE4A+KFIDeAXwBQx0JFgBGKXERIaAWwBGWqAB8qdWroD0PqABqAIa0AJa4ZuDQMABMNgjIiJqh2ADm7p70vv7BYRHm0QDM8XaOLjpQflAAkthqIeFiDtSIUC5QQRzYobzYUADGvcBBKSnpAAYKtOORFjAALCXIZVrZNXUNuE0twG3QnZw9fYPYw6NpUJNeM0A

Comment: @tokland thank you! I'm not sure this pattern had existed before :)